# How do I add Discord Buttons to Discord.JS v14.2.0 using Slash Commands to trigger an embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

```
const { MessageActionRow, MessageButton, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'client',
    description: "Check to see how Nonay is holding up!",
    showHelp: false,

    execute({ client, inter }) {
        const commands = client.commands.filter(x => x.showHelp !== false);

        const button = new MessageButton()
            .setLabel('Click Me')
            .setStyle('PRIMARY')
            .setCustomId('exampleButton');

        const row = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(button);

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#0CEC1D')
            .setAuthor(client.user.username, client.user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 1024, dynamic: true }))
            .setTitle(' Client Info')
            .setDescription("``Nonay Client Ver``\nv3.4.9\n\n``Client Performance``\nExcellent\n\n``Client Discord.js``\nv14.2.0\n\n``BETA Whitelist Commands``\ncontroller, update, filter, console")
            .setFooter('Powered by Nonay', inter.member.avatarURL({ dynamic: true }));

        inter.reply({ embeds: [embed], components: [row] });
    }, };
```

So I have been trying everything to get Discord buttons to work with my slash commands, I am still new to this all so I have no clue what I am doing. After this, what do I do to make the button produce another embed?

Comment: Are you sure you are using Discord.js v14? If yes, does it show errors? You are using a couple classes that are not in Discord.js v14 anymore.

Comment: You might be right but whenever I run npm list it shows discord.js as v14 but i have no clue if thats true or not

Comment: Then you are most likely using v14. But it should throw errors then when trying to run the bot because literally every single class you are importing from Discord.js does not exist in v14.

Comment: well i mean its running fine atm its up rn